# почему ReferenceError: Clock is not defined что я пропустил

Tags: javascript

есть два класса в a.js и в b.js

a.js

```
class Clock {
  clg(){
    console.log(`a`)
    }
 }
```

b.js

```
class ExtendedClock extends Clock {};

let d = new ExtendedClock()
d.clg()
```

в VCCode в терминале пишу node b и не запускается: переношу код в a.js все работает

Comment: Не видно экспорта `Clock`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто нужно воспользоваться экспортом в одном файле и импортом в другом.

a.js

```
export default class Clock {
  clg() {
    console.log(`a`);
  }
}
```

b.js

```
import Clock from './a';

class ExtendedClock extends Clock {}

let d = new ExtendedClock();
d.clg();
```

Либо с использованием старого синтаксиса.

a.js

```
class Clock {
  clg() {
    console.log(`a`);
  }
}

module.exports = { Clock };
```

b.js

```
const Clock = require('./a').Clock;

class ExtendedClock extends Clock {}

let d = new ExtendedClock();
d.clg();
```

Comment: Если это node, то лучше через require

Comment: @АлександрЛесив обновил)

Comment: спасибо за помощь))